# How does setState in React work in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm trying to set the state of an object inside my array. I have achieved it but I don't understand it.

```
toggleVisited = countryCode => {
  var countries = [ ...this.state.countries ];
  var countryToChange = countries.find(country => country.code === countryCode);
  countryToChange.visited = !countryToChange.visited;
  this.setState({ countryToChange });
}
```

I understand (mainly) what is happening, up to the last `this.setState` line.

I changed the code to `this.setState({})` and it still worked. I always thought set state was setting the new value for an object key. Why (no matter what I put in here), is it still setting it correctly?

Comment: That's weird...

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman it's not if their component(s) are not pure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `countryToChange.visited = !countryToChange.visited`, you are mutating your current state. [Don't do this.](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) Create a new object instead:

```
toggleVisited = countryCode => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        const countries = prevState.countries.map(country => country.code !== countryCode
            ? country
            : {
                ...country,
                visited: !country.visited
            })
        const countryToChange = countries.find(country => country.code === countryCode)

        return {
            countries,
            countryToChange
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Note that you can also pass a function to `setState` which will receive the current state as an argument. So something along the lines of
`this.setState(prevState => { var countryToChange = prevState.countries... `

Comment: @HalilC Good catch. I changed it. I also missed that OP probably wanted to change `countries`, too. So I added a `map` to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

React component's state should be treated as immutable, but you can actually change its values.
Your code will work for every setState() you do because setState triggers re-rendering, and since you've already changed the state `countryToChange.visited = !countryToChange.visited;`, the component will be re-rendered with the new state.

Answer (score 0):

```
toggleVisited = countryCode => {
  var countries = [ ...this.state.countries ];
  //here you use spread operator to "clone" all countries
  var countryToChange = countries.find(country => country.code === countryCode);
  //you filter all your countries and get the one with the CC you want
  countryToChange.visited = !countryToChange.visited;
  //your country is an object, and you change visited prop to it's opposite
  //boolean, !false == true
  this.setState({ countryToChange });
  //you just changed your country visited prop, in react you cannot change
  //deep props so, you re-set {countryToChange: countryToChange}
  //or simply {countryToChange} due to new ES features
}
```